# UIWebView in tabbed application (Xcode)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xcode4.3

I'm just starting to learn Xcode, and have run in to some problems...

I've made a tabbed application in Xcode 4.3 which works as deired. But I previously made a simple UIWebView application, that I would now like to implement into one of the tabs on the new application.

This is what I've done in the classes for FirstViewController:

```
//  FirstViewController.h
//  SafeLine
//
//  Created by Camilla Fröberg on 2012-03-27.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 SafeLine Sweden AB. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *webDisplay;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIWebView *webDisplay;


@end
```

And the FirstViewController.m:

```
//  FirstViewController.m
//  SafeLine
//
//  Created by Camilla Fröberg on 2012-03-27.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 SafeLine Sweden AB. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()


@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize webDisplay;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webDisplay loadRequest:requestObj];



    [super viewDidLoad];
}



// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


@end
```

When running the application I won't get any error message, and it will not show the website, instead it will only show an empty view...

Any help is appreciated!

// Best regards 
Camilla from Sweden

Comment: Did you remember to hook up the UIWebView in Interface Builder? You declared it as an IBOutlet but you need to manually connect it. If not, this would cause it to be `nil`, so nothing would happen. Your code looks fine otherwise.

Comment: I tried everything, but I didn't even think to check if they were connected... Now that they are it works fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should check if you connected the UIWebView in the Interface Builder with IBOutlet.